# upload big files to server

Tags: file-upload, node.js, upload, nginx, uploading

I want to upload big files to server. What is the best way to this:

```
1) using node.js library, such as formidable
2) using nginx upload module
```

or may be other more faster and better solution ?

Comment: What kind of server? Are you looking to use nginx just to handle the uploads or do you already have nginx up and running and would like to upload to the nginx server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to upload big files nginx would be the better solution.

However if you want to stream files, download as you upload, then node.js would be the right tool.